# Solr multiple filter tagging / excluding

Tags: solr, tagging, facet

I am trying to apply filter tagging for Solr search [Tagging_and_excluding_Filters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Tagging_and_excluding_Filters).

The challenge is to apply multiple tagging at the same time (for multiple select options on a single page). e.g.

`q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&fq={!tag=doc}document:1&facet=on&facet.field={!ex=dt}doctype&facet.field={!ex=doc}document`

But for some reason excluding works only for one filter and other gets unnoticed. Is there any problem with my syntax? Can anyone suggest a better method?

Comment: This is the most current docs - https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_2/faceting.html#tagging-and-excluding-filters - The ones in the q/a are not available any longer.

Answer (score 7):

I'm having a similiar problem to solve and it seemed to work by just using a comma to seperate excluded tags:

From: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#facet.field

> Filter exclusion is supported for all types of facets. Both the tag
>   and ex local params may specify multiple values by separating them
>   with commas.

So I guess you'd use it like: `{!ex=doc,dt}`

Answer (score 2):

This answer may not be timely, but i think this should resolve your issue.

Try adding both the tags in both the ex clauses. 
I did that and it worked for me for a similar case.

```
q=mainquery&fq=status:public&fq={!tag=dt}doctype:pdf&fq={!tag=doc}document:1&facet=on&facet.field={!ex=dt,doc}doctype&facet.field={!ex=dt,doc}document
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly the http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SimpleFacetParameters#Multi-Select_Faceting_and_LocalParams section
would help you further than the from you mentioned one.

Best regards!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, but I have already checked that link.

Comment: Are you really sure about that? You do not use the 'key' local param label in your statements above, which you should to resolve your problem.